# Clang-format "AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType : None" doesn't work

Tags: clang-format

I want to use clang-format, but it always starts with a new line after the returnType. I read the documentation and tried

"AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType : None"

but this seams to have no effect. I'm using clang-format 6.0 in ubuntu 17.10 inside QT creator.

is:

```
int
    main() {
    ...
}
```

expected:

```
int main() {
    ...
}
```

Version: clang-format 6.0, clang-format config file:

```
BasedOnStyle: Mozilla
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments : true
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands: true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: InlineOnly
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
    AfterClass: true
    AfterControlStatement: false
    AfterEnum: false
    AfterFunction: false
    AfterNamespace: false
    AfterObjCDeclaration: false
    AfterStruct: false
    AfterUnion: false
    AfterExternBlock: false
    BeforeCatch: true
    BeforeElse: true
    SplitEmptyFunction: false
    SplitEmptyRecord: false
    SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: true
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakStringLiterals : false
ColumnLimit: 120
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DerivePointerAlignment: true
DisableFormat: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: true
FixNamespaceComments: true
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentPPDirectives: AfterHash
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
Language: Cpp
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments: true
SortIncludes: true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword : false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 3
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: true
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInParentheses: true
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce on a minimal example (your C is minimal, but your clang-format config isn't)?

Comment: Minimal clang-format:

BasedOnStyle: Mozilla
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None

Answer (score 6):

You should read the documentation carefully:

> RTBS_None (in configuration: None) Break after return type
>   automatically. PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine is taken into account.

So "None" doesn't mean that it will never break after return type, it will take into account other settings like `BinPackParameters`, `BraceWrapping`, etc. and their penalties.

To make breaking after return type less likely or "almost" turned off you can set `PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine` to a very high value, for example:

```
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000000
```

Please note that I'm not that familiar what exactly penalties numbers mean, how they relate to each other and how the final line breaking is calculated. You'll have to find that information elsewhere (source code of clang-format?).

Comment: If you are interested in penalties - there short explanation at https://youtu.be/s7JmdCfI__c?t=630. Briefly, penalties used only for long-long lines, when the line should be splitted on several lines. It can be splitted in multiple ways, and penalties helps to choose the best way, in the way when sum of penalties will be the minimum. So, if you set PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine to a small value, comparatively to other penalties, it will prefer this option in most cases.

Answer (score 6):

Just try to assign the deprecated property 'AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType' to 'None' too.

This works well for me.

```
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
```

Comment: This is because the Mozilla style sets both to `TopLevel` so both must be overridden even though `AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue on the minimal example you provide as comment:

```
$ cat .clang-format 
 BasedOnStyle: Mozilla
 AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
$ cat main.c 
int main() {
        return 0;
}
$ clang-format main.c 
int
main()
{
  return 0;
}
$ clang-format --version
clang-format version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
```

Indeed, you have also set `IndentWrappedFunctionNames`, whose behavior is exactly the one you obtain. If you don't want this behavior, then don't set `IndentWrappedFunctionNames`.